# How can I access another window from an opened one in c#

Tags: c#

I currently have a login Window that opens the MainWindow with the btnClick event to trigger. By clicking a button from this Window, this Window should close and open the Main one.

I tried it but I still have no idea how to access Main Window from current one.

Here is the code below. Hope to get some help. Thanks! :P

---

```
using ....;

..........;

using ....;

namespace SampleWindowApp

{

    public partial class Login : Form

    {
        public Login()

        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

        }

        private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ConnectionDAL obj = new ConnectionDAL();
            BL.LoginBL objBL = new BL.LoginBL();
            if(objBL.ValidateBL(txtUsername.Text, txtPass.Text))
                {
                    Mainfrmcs.Show;  <---
                    this.Close;      <---
                }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password.");
        }  
    }
}
```

---

The two lines show me the error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: Method invocations should use the `[MethodName].([parameters]);` notation. i.e. `Mainfrmcs.Show();` and `this.Close();`

Comment: That solves the second error, but the first one still not working:(

Comment: Mainfrmcs is a Type, to create an instance of a type you use the `new` keyword. Look at Tripesdeporc's answer for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are opening your form after logging in, instead of writing `Mainfrmcs.Show` you need to write `new Mainfrmcs().Show()` and since `this.Close()` closes the program, you need to change it `this.Hide()`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the this.Close() closes the program because it is (most probably) defined as the startup object in your Program.cs
**Application.Run(new Login());**

You could, instead, add a new class (class StartupObject) and then, in that object do the Login MyLoginWindow = new Login(); Login.Show(); AND THEN, you can add the MainForm MyMainForm = new MainForm(); MainForm.Show(); this.Close();

Answer (score 1):

If suppose you work in WinForms.
Before showing or closing anything you want, you have to define it.
Actually, you try to show a form that exists but has no object affected to it and it's the same for the closing.
All you have to do is :

```
.
.
.
if(objBL.ValidateBL(txtUsername.Text, txtPass.Text))
    {
        Form Mainfrmcs = new Mainfrmcs();
        // I suppose there is no MdiParent if you're closing the other but if there was :
        Mainfrmcs.MdiParent = this;
        Mainfrmcs.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
else
.
.
.
```

(the method .Close() does not exit the program if a window is still open. Application.Exit() will)
Hope this helps !